# Gradle, Cucumber and Windows command length

Tags: java, windows, gradle, kotlin, cucumber

I have been using the [Gradle Util Plugin](https://github.com/viswaramamoorthy/gradle-util-plugins) to overcome the Windows command execution error because of limitation to command line length greater than 32 and this seems to be working for `build`, `bootRun` and `test` tasks, however, for my `cucumber` task

```
 task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "org.junit.runner.JUnitCore"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['io.biomex.spog.steps.RunCukesTest']
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see the classpath is generated using the various sourceSets which result in the Windows command exceeding the length limitation. Can anyone advise how I can change the above task to utilize the Manifest jar created by the util plugin or a provide an alternative solution?

Comment: Can you show the error you are getting?

Comment: I was getting exactly the same error as has been described in the Gradle Util Plugin readme: Fix for windows gradle long classpath issue. Fixes JavaExec tasks that error out with message "CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long"

Answer (score 1):

```
task cucumber() {
dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
doLast {
    javaexec {
        main = "org.junit.runner.JUnitCore"
        classpath = files("${buildDir}/mfjars/junitPlatformTest_ManifestJar.jar")
        args = ['io.biomex.spog.steps.RunCukesTest']
    }
}
```

This works, but not sure if I like the name of the jar or having to reference it in this fashion.